# Google Earth Engine Internal Error ExportImageToDrive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-earth-engine

I have been trying to figure out why this image won't export to my drive and I am stuck.  I believe this is a syntax problem, but the server error message is pretty cryptic.

If I have the simple script that:

1. loads the NLCD 2016 `dataset` for a user uploaded asset `table`
2. selects the `impervious_descriptor` dataset,
3. Maps GEE image
4. prints out various properties of the image

Why is the `Export.image.ToDrive` command failing with an `Error: Internal error`?

```java
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/hamilldaniel/MCDD_West_AirTrans_drain_area");

var dataset = ee.Image('USGS/NLCD/NLCD2016').clip(table);

var imperviousVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 95.0,
  palette: [
    '466b9f', 'd1def8', 'dec5c5', 'd99282', 'eb0000', 'ab0000', 'b3ac9f',
    '68ab5f', '1c5f2c', 'b5c58f', 'af963c', 'ccb879', 'dfdfc2', 'd1d182',
    'a3cc51', '82ba9e', 'dcd939', 'ab6c28', 'b8d9eb', '6c9fb8'
  ],
};

var impv_desc = dataset.select('impervious_descriptor');
Map.addLayer(impv_desc, imperviousVis, 'Impervious');
Map.centerObject(table, 12);

print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', impv_desc.projection());
print('Scale in meters:', impv_desc.projection().nominalScale());

Export.image.toDrive({image : impv_desc, 
                      description: 'MCDD_West_AirTrans_Impv_desc', 
                      folder: 'PLMS_PRECIP', 
                      scale : 30,
                      maxPixels: 3000000000000,
                      region: table,
                      crs : 'EPSG:4326', 
                      });
```